# longest integer vector partition

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Given an nonegetive integer vector $\overset{\rightarrow}{m}=(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)$, how to find the longest distinct integer vector sequence $\overset{\rightarrow}{a_1},\ldots,\overset{\rightarrow}{a_n}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\overset{\rightarrow}{a_i}=\overset{\rightarrow}{m}.$$ where $\overset{\rightarrow}{a_i}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)$ are nonegetive integer vectors ?

I know the sequence must satisfies the property that if $\overset{\rightarrow}{a_i}=\overset{\rightarrow}{a}+\overset{\rightarrow}{b}$ then $\overset{\rightarrow}{b}\text{ or }\overset{\rightarrow}{a}=\overset{\rightarrow}{a_j}$ for some $j$, since otherwise one can split $\overset{\rightarrow}{a_i}$ to make the sequence longer.

So, I'm wondering whether this condition also sufficient for the sequence to be longest.

**EDIT**: I just find a counterexample, let $\overset{\rightarrow}{m}=(6,1,2,2,2)$, consider the sequence $(1,0,0,0,0),(2,0,0,0,0),(3,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,1,1)$ which satisfies the condition but not the longest.

So, now the question becomes how to find an efficient algorithm to solve the original question?

Comment: So you can have $a_i=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ but only for a single $i$?

Comment: @Henry yes, but you can exclude it if convenient, this will not influence the result.

Comment: Thank you - I was just trying to understand the question.